# How to draw a filled arc in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

In matplotlib, I would like draw an filled arc which looks like this:

[image: Filled Arc Example]

The following code results in an unfilled line arc:

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fg, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

pac = mpatches.Arc([0, -2.5], 5, 5, angle=0, theta1=45, theta2=135)
ax.add_patch(pac)

ax.axis([-2, 2, -2, 2])
ax.set_aspect("equal")
fg.canvas.draw()
```

The [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html?highlight=arc#matplotlib.patches.Arc) says that filled arcs are not possible.
What would be the best way to draw one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[@jeanrjc's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30643392/4177384) almost gets you there, but it adds a completely unnecessary white triangle, which will hide other objects as well (see figure below, version 1).

This is a simpler approach, which only adds a polygon of the arc:

Basically we create a series of points (`points`) along the edge of the circle (from `theta1` to `theta2`). This is already enough, as we can set the `close` flag in the `Polygon` constructor which will add the line from the last to the first point (creating a closed arc).

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def arc_patch(center, radius, theta1, theta2, ax=None, resolution=50, **kwargs):
    # make sure ax is not empty
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    # generate the points
    theta = np.linspace(np.radians(theta1), np.radians(theta2), resolution)
    points = np.vstack((radius*np.cos(theta) + center[0], 
                        radius*np.sin(theta) + center[1]))
    # build the polygon and add it to the axes
    poly = mpatches.Polygon(points.T, closed=True, **kwargs)
    ax.add_patch(poly)
    return poly
```

And then we apply it:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)

# @jeanrjc solution, which might hide other objects in your plot
ax[0].plot([-1,1],[1,-1], 'r', zorder = -10)
filled_arc((0.,0.3), 1, 90, 180, ax[0], 'blue')
ax[0].set_title('version 1')

# simpler approach, which really is just the arc
ax[1].plot([-1,1],[1,-1], 'r', zorder = -10)
arc_patch((0.,0.3), 1, 90, 180, ax=ax[1], fill=True, color='blue')
ax[1].set_title('version 2')

# axis settings
for a in ax:
    a.set_aspect('equal')
    a.set_xlim(-1.5, 1.5)
    a.set_ylim(-1.5, 1.5)

plt.show()
```

Result (version 2):

[image]

Comment: Just curious, why the downvote?! How does that not address the question?

Comment: Well, I didn't downvote. I'm rather happy that you manage to improve my solution, although if you could detail a bit how you populate `points`, it would be even nicer. btw, if you downvoted my answer I can't see any reason why.

Comment: No, I didn't downvote yours, in fact im going to upvote it. Your solution is nice too, I like that you were able to leverage existing functionality (the wedge). There was someone else on a downvoting spree (for no apparent reason).
Regarding the population of `points` you are right, I'll make that part simpler.

Comment: Thanks for addressing the covering up problem problem in @jeanrc's answer (To avoid up/down-voting issue: I am giving you +1).

Answer (score 10):

You can use `fill_between` to achieve this

```
 import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import numpy as np

 fg, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

 r=2.
 yoff=-1
 x=np.arange(-1.,1.05,0.05)
 y=np.sqrt(r-x**2)+yoff

 ax.fill_between(x,y,0)

 ax.axis([-2, 2, -2, 2])
 ax.set_aspect("equal")
 fg.canvas.draw()
```

Play around with r and yoff to move the arc

[image]

**EDIT:**

OK, so you want to be able to plot arbitrary angles? You just need to find the equation of the chord, rather than using a flat line like above. Here's a function to do just that:

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fg, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

col='rgbkmcyk'

def filled_arc(center,r,theta1,theta2):

    # Range of angles
    phi=np.linspace(theta1,theta2,100)

    # x values
    x=center[0]+r*np.sin(np.radians(phi))

    # y values. need to correct for negative values in range theta=90--270
    yy = np.sqrt(r-x**2)
    yy = [-yy[i] if phi[i] > 90 and phi[i] < 270 else yy[i] for i in range(len(yy))]

    y = center[1] + np.array(yy)

    # Equation of the chord
    m=(y[-1]-y[0])/(x[-1]-x[0])
    c=y[0]-m*x[0]
    y2=m*x+c

    # Plot the filled arc
    ax.fill_between(x,y,y2,color=col[theta1/45])

# Lets plot a whole range of arcs
for i in [0,45,90,135,180,225,270,315]:
    filled_arc([0,0],1,i,i+45)

ax.axis([-2, 2, -2, 2])
ax.set_aspect("equal")
fg.savefig('filled_arc.png')
```

And here's the output:

[image]

Comment: Just curious, why the downvote? Does this not answer the question?

Comment: I guess it's because although you manage to recreate the shape asked (in a clever way), it does not allow you to do a filled arc from `theta1=0` to `theta2=45` for instance. Or if you could, please describe a bit more.

Comment: you can, you just need a bit of imagination. I'll update my answer now.

Comment: ``fill_between()`` is a nice idea. I only asked implicitly for the coordinate transformations, so it is valid (To avoid further rating confusions: I am giving you +1 for it).

Comment: Using `fill_between()` is a way of doing it too. Agreed. However, the result is the exact same `patch` as I create in my answer.

Comment: thanks. hopefully the updated answer allows you to do your coordinate transformations

Comment: Thanks for the update. As already noted, your answer and @hitzg's answer are equal, though I going to accept hitzg's answer, because it came first and I am only allowed to choose one.

Comment: @Dietrich: Fair enough. Glad you got it doing what what want!

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simpler workaround. Use the hatch argument in your mpatches.Arc command. If you repeat symbols with the hatch argument it increases the density of the patterning. I find that if you use 6 dashes, '-', or 6 dots, '.' (others probably also work), then it solidly fills in the arc as desired. When I run this

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

plt.axes()
pac = mpatches.Arc([0, -2.5], 5, 5, 45, theta1=45, theta2=135, hatch = '......')
plt.gca().add_patch(pac)
pac.set_color('cyan')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

I get this:

[Arc filled with dense dot hatch and rotated 45 degrees just for show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOEdB.png)

Comment: This solution is image resolution dependent, with enough zoom is always possible to notice the points.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, this is the only answer in this thread that fill an ellipse arc and not a circle arc

Comment: Heracho, 1) True, unfortunately. That is why I introduced it as a "simpler workaround". Different hatching styles can help make it appear thicker. It's annoying that the edge color doesn't match the pseudo-solid color filling the shape. 2) Looks like this solution is still the only one that uses `mpatches.Arc`, so I suppose you are right!

Answer (score 5):

You can draw a wedge, and then hide part of it with a triangle:

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def filled_arc(center, radius, theta1, theta2, ax, color):

    circ = mpatches.Wedge(center, radius, theta1, theta2, fill=True, color=color)
    pt1 = (radius * (np.cos(theta1*np.pi/180.)) + center[0],
           radius * (np.sin(theta1*np.pi/180.)) + center[1])
    pt2 = (radius * (np.cos(theta2*np.pi/180.)) + center[0],
           radius * (np.sin(theta2*np.pi/180.)) + center[1])
    pt3 = center
    pol = mpatches.Polygon([pt1, pt2, pt3], color=ax.get_axis_bgcolor(),
                           ec=ax.get_axis_bgcolor(), lw=2 )
    ax.add_patch(circ)
    ax.add_patch(pol)
```

and then you can call it:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
filled_arc((0,0), 1, 45, 135, ax[0], "blue")
filled_arc((0,0), 1, 0, 40, ax[1], "blue")
```

and you get:

[image: filled_arc]

or:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
for i in range(0,360,45):
    filled_arc((0,0), 1, i, i+45, ax, plt.cm.jet(i))
```

and you get:

[image]

HTH

Comment: While this gets the job done in this basic example, it will give you unwanted results if you have other artists in your figure which you want to be below the arc (as the white triangle hides them too).

Comment: I like the approach of combining wedge and triangle. As @hitzg noted there might be problems of covering other objects. +1 for the nice pictures

Answer (score 0):

The command `ax.get_axis_bgcolor()` needs to be replaced by `ax.get_fc()` for newer matplotlib.

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment to another answer.