# How to plot half-ellipses in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, plot

I need to plot half-ellipses (or to be precise, half-elliptical disks, hence I can't use matplotlib to plot an [elliptical arc](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html)).

I found OpenCV can do this with this syntax: `cv2.Ellipse(img, center, axes, angle, start_angle, end_angle, color, thickness=1, lineType=8, shift=0)`, but there is one thing that really bothers me. I want to use standard x and y coordinates, not pixels. Also, I will need to plot half ellipses with non-integer radius, and it seem OpenCV can't do that (for the same reason of having pixel coordinates).

So, I need a code that can do what OpenCV does (with the same `angle + start_angle + end_angle` structure), but without requiring me to work in pixels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use matplotlib [arc](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#module-matplotlib.patches) is you didn't want them filled in. For a filled arc, you can use the accepted solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642391/how-to-draw-a-filled-arc-in-matplotlib) where a generic patch is defined and combine with the matplotlib ellipse [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/ellipse_demo.html),

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.random as rnd
import numpy as np

def arc_patch(xy, width, height, theta1=0., theta2=180., resolution=50, **kwargs):

    # generate the points
    theta = np.linspace(np.radians(theta1), np.radians(theta2), resolution)
    points = np.vstack((width*np.cos(theta)  + xy[0], 
                        height*np.sin(theta) + xy[1]))
    # build the polygon and add it to the axes
    poly = mpatches.Polygon(points.T, closed=True, **kwargs)

    return poly

NUM = 10
arcs = []
for i in range(NUM):
    r = rnd.rand()*360.
    arcs.append(arc_patch(xy=rnd.rand(2)*10, width=1., 
                height=1., theta1=r, theta2=r+180.))

# axis settings
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
for a in arcs:
    ax.add_artist(a)
    a.set_clip_box(ax.bbox)
    a.set_alpha(0.5)
    a.set_facecolor(rnd.rand(3))

ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(0, 10)

plt.show()
```

Which looks like,
[image]

Comment: FYI, `matplotlib.patches.Arc` can make filled half-ellipses.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this @Syrtis Major? The official docs for `matplotlib.patches.Arc` here: http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#module-matplotlib.patches explicitly says "Because it performs various optimizations, it can not be filled."

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the docs, but just tried it (see answer below). I'm not sure why, maybe the docs is a bit outdated?

Comment: I just realize that `Arc`s can not fill themselves indeed, but the `PatchCollection` can fill them. That's why my solution works.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`matplotlib.patches.Arc`](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Arc) can make half-ellipses, just specify the keywords `theta1=0.0, theta2=180.0` (or 90 to 270).
I've written a wrapper function named `arcs` for making a scatter plot of `Arc`s.
It uses the PatchCollection, should have better performance and enable colorbar.
You can find it at gist [(link)](https://gist.github.com/syrte/592a062c562cd2a98a83).

Here's an example:

```
a = np.arange(11)
arcs(a, a, w=4, h=a, rot=a*30, theta1=0.0, theta2=180.0, 
     c=a, alpha=0.5, edgecolor='none')
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

---

A brief implementation of `arcs` is posted below for completeness as  Ed Smith suggested.

```
def arcs(x, y, w, h, rot=0.0, theta1=0.0, theta2=360.0,
         c='b', **kwargs):
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.patches import Arc
    from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

    if np.isscalar(c):
        kwargs.setdefault('color', c)
        c = None

    zipped = np.broadcast(x, y, w, h, rot, theta1, theta2)
    patches = [Arc((x_, y_), w_, h_, rot_, t1_, t2_)
               for x_, y_, w_, h_, rot_, t1_, t2_ in zipped]
    collection = PatchCollection(patches, **kwargs)

    if c is not None:
        c = np.broadcast_to(c, zipped.shape).ravel()
        collection.set_array(c)

    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.add_collection(collection)
    return collection
```

The full version can be found at gist [(link)](https://gist.github.com/syrte/592a062c562cd2a98a83).

Comment: Your solution looks good. Is it possible to extract out the minimal code for an example of using PatchCollections so as to give a self contained answer here?