# color matplotlib patch with 2 colors or a gradient

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I need to coloring an Ellipse with two different colors. This could be done half and half or better, an horizontal gradient.

I would like to keep using matplotlib patches and not to use equations to draw the ellipse.

I'm using this minimal code to point the problem.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatch

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.add_patch(mpatch.Ellipse(xy = [0.5, 0.5], width= 0.75, height=0.5, facecolor = 'blue'))
plt.show()
```

Anserws to [How to draw a filled arc in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642391/how-to-draw-a-filled-arc-in-matplotlib) are directed to fill a circle arc except for one that can fill a ellipse arc.

This is a cartoon of what I need

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958835/matplotlib-color-gradient-in-patches

Comment: Both solutions proposed in that thread do not used matplotlib patches.

Comment: I was thinking in to use wedge patch to draw half ellipses. but I don't know how to transform the semicircles in to 'semi-ellipses'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw a filled arc in matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642391/how-to-draw-a-filled-arc-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The patch arc can draw a semi ellipse, but by default it can not be filled.

I found how to fill and arc in:
[How to draw a filled arc in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642391/how-to-draw-a-filled-arc-in-matplotlib).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatch

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.add_patch(mpatch.Arc(xy = [0.5, 0.5], width= 0.75, height=0.5, angle=.0, theta1= 90.0, theta2=-90.0, color = 'blue', hatch = 'OOOO'))
ax.add_patch(mpatch.Arc(xy = [0.5, 0.5], width= 0.75, height=0.5, angle=.0, theta1=-90.0, theta2= 90.0, color = 'green', hatch = 'OOOO'))
```

[image]

Comment: This solution depends on image resolution, whit enough zoom it's possible to notice the points instead of a solid color.